# Вывод из БД без обновления страницы

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

Нужен скрипт вывода из БД без перезагрузки страницы, сайт висит на хостинге, динамическое обновление ни в какие ворота не катятся...

БД: id - name - mess

Суть, что когда добавляется строка в БД, она сразу отображается на странице сайта.

Comment: через JS отображайте сразу в HTML... $(selector).append(content,function(index,html))

Comment: несколько путей. 1.вебсокеты 2.ajax + триггеры в базе на изменение + отдельный обработчик на отслеживание изменений в базе. Ничего сложного, однако, для получения этого "ничего сложного" надо забыть этот недоязык под названием PHP  и использовать нормальные средства разработки.

Comment: @Spouk вебсокеты будут работать на хостинге? Потому-что я где-то читал, что хостинги не поддерживают это, только личные сервера.

Comment: @sasha-osipov2 почему нет? Это обвес поверх TCP. Поэтому все упирается в поддержку используемого браузера, но по статистике поддержка в настоящем вебсокетов браузерами более 95%. Так что ответ - да, все будет работать.

Comment: @Spouk а на мобильных устройствах будет поддерживаться?

Comment: @sasha-osipov2 http://caniuse.com/#search=websocket да, но не всех. Посмотри список поддерживаемых браузеров, включая "мобильные" девайсы.

Comment: @Spouk Отлично, а есть скрипт получение ответа из БД или прям полный с выводом?

Comment: @sasha-osipov2 я не смогу ответить на твой вопрос, ибо не использую php совсем. Работаю с Golang.

Comment: @Spouk хорошо, ну всё равно спасибо, хотябы дали направление

Answer (score -1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1" />
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mybd');
if($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $row['id'].$row['title'];
echo 'Эти значения получены из БД';
}
}?>

</body>
</html>
```

Данный скрипт получает значения из mysql, и с помощью тега meta обновляется каждую секунду